# automatically append hashtag # in all url using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to add a hashtag (#) in all pages, the reason is that the header height is too long, and I don't want the user to scroll down every time the page loads to see the content of the page.

I have added a link called "hash" so that the page will point to the title page instead

```
<!-- Page Title -->
<div class="flexslider">
    <a name="hash"></a>
    <div class="titlepage"><h2>{{ $page_title }}</h2></div>    
</div><!--/flexslider-->
<!-- End Page Title -->
```

I am using Laravel 4, not sure if Laravel has a function to append it to all URL e.g. my_project/employee#hash

Comment: Is javascript an option? Because it would be a lot easier than doing it in Laravel

Comment: How to do it using javascript? Any suggestion and recommendation are welcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different approaches. (Disclaimer: I'm using jQuery here, not pure javascript)

### 1. Add the hash to every link

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href]').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('href', $(this).prop('href')+'#hash');
    });
});
```

### 2. Add the hash to the current page

```
$(window).load(function(){
    window.location.hash = 'hash';
});
```

With the second method instead of just setting the hash you could also use javascript to scroll down with an animation. Like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22282504/1903366) (without the click handler)